# How can I programmatically generate textviews inside layout

Tags: java, android

I need to generate TextView inside a layout from a random, API generated, ArrayList. I cant seem to find a way in which they appear in one line, like a String, one after the other and also shift below once the line has reached the max layout width limit. I want each TextView to be sperate as I want to click them.

[Would like to achieve something like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noZMw.jpg)

This is the current code but the line stops and I don't know how to shift it below. Currently I am using a relative layout as the base layout but it is not necessary.

```
for (int i = 0; i < abc.size(); i++) {
    titleText = new TextView(this);
    titleText.setId(i);
    titleText.setText(abc.get(i));
    relativeLayout.addView(titleText, i);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, titleText.getId() - 1);
    titleText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    titleText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.teal_700));
    tvArray.add(titleText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

In your xml

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/my_ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

And write code in **yourjava.class**

```
LinearLayout my_ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_ll);
        for(int i=0;i<your_number_of_textviews;i++)
        {
            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            text.setText(""+i);
            my_ll.addView(text);
        }
```

Comment: I wanted them to appear horizontally and shift below once the covering width has ended would that be possible with this?

Comment: change orientation to horizontal in linear layout

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution would have solved it. First before the loop retrieve somewhere the width of the screen by using -

```
Point screenSizePoint = new Point();
// this gives you the furthest point from 0,0 e.g. 1440x3168
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(screenSizePoint);
int sum = 0;
```

Then you retrieve your abc list somewhere.
And then you always compute the width of the current TextView by using this

```
titleText.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int width = titleText.getMeasuredWidth();
sum += width;

if (sum >= screenSizePoint.x) {
   // shift to next line
}
```

and sum it up with the width of text views placed before and if the width is bigger than the screen width you just begin on another line.